# How to draw with content side by side in jetpack compose

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack-compose-canvas

I am using to `drawBehind` in my `Column`. I want to draw side by side. I draw line to specific coordinate and want my `Text` side of it. I tried this code

```
@Preview(showBackground = true)
@Composable
fun ItemView() {
    val names = listOf("Captain" to "Vice Captain")
    LazyColumn(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize()) {
        itemsIndexed(names) { index, item ->

            var titleCoordinates by remember { mutableStateOf<LayoutCoordinates?>(null) }
            Column(
                modifier = Modifier
                    .fillMaxWidth()
                    .drawBehind {
                        val titleBounds = titleCoordinates?.boundsInParent()
                        if (titleBounds != null) {
                            val offset = Offset(x = center.x / 2, y = titleBounds.top)
                            drawLine(
                                color = Color.Black,
                                start = offset,
                                end = offset.copy(y = size.height),
                                strokeWidth = 2.dp.toPx(),
                            )
                        }
                    }
            ) {
                Box(
                    Modifier
                        .padding(top = 24.dp)
                        .onGloballyPositioned { titleCoordinates = it }
                ) {
                    Text(text = item.first, color = Color.Red)
                }
                Text(text = item.second, color = Color.Blue)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Actual Output**

[image]

I can add `padding(start = 120.dp)` in `Column` to get my below output. I want to avoid these padding. Is it possible to achieve below output?

**Expected Output**

[image]

Many Thanks

Comment: Why do you draw to Column with padding before drawBehind modifier? You can easily draw on left side of both `Text`s if you put them inside a Column

Comment: And you are using center of a Column,  for x coordinate , that has fillMaxWidth would return half width of parent which  supposed to be as in actual output

Comment: Can you please provide me example for this to fix this problem?

Comment: I didn't understand what your goal exactly is. Why don't you want to add padding to start and you can add a padding after drawBehind to add another padding after line and before texts

Comment: Do you want content to be placed based on where your line is drawn?  If that's the case why do you position line based on Box coordinates?

Comment: Oh yes I fixed the problem by adding padding before  of `drawBehind` and after adding a padding.. Thanks great suggestion..

Comment: yes content to be placed on where line drawn. How can we do with Box coordinates?

Comment: By using Modifier.drawWithContent and translating position of drawing and actual content. Second translate is moving actual content from the position line is drawn

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you you wish to align drawing with actual Content of a Composable you can use `Modifier.drawWithContent{}`. drawContent() draws what's inside the Composable that this modifier is assigned to while you can position content and drawing based on each other or other requirements.

[image]

```
@Preview
@Composable
fun ItemView() {
    Column(
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxWidth()
            .padding(20.dp)

    ) {
        val names = listOf("Captain" to "Vice Captain")
        LazyColumn(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize().border(2.dp, Color.Green)) {
            itemsIndexed(names) { index, item ->

                Column(
                    modifier = Modifier
                        .padding(top = 24.dp)
                        .fillMaxWidth()
                        .drawWithContent {

                            translate(
                                left= 120.dp.toPx(), top = 0f
                            ){
                                drawLine(
                                    color = Color.Black,
                                    start = Offset(0f,0f),
                                    end = Offset(0f, size.height),
                                    strokeWidth = 2.dp.toPx(),
                                )

                                translate(
                                    left= 10.dp.toPx(), top = 0f
                                ){
                                    this@drawWithContent.drawContent()
                                }

                            }
                        }


                ) {
                    Text(text = item.first, color = Color.Red)
                    Text(text = item.second, color = Color.Blue)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This is the easiest way to align content based on what you draw. Since you can set position of content based on where your drawings are. Maybe not an issue for this question but as the things get more complex being able to change position, scale or rotation of content with such an ease is amazing. One of the reasons i like drawing with compose

Comment: Thanks @Thracian for teaching me. I am not great in maths. So that's why I made mistake all of this.